# ENOENT error when doing ionic start

Tags: ionic2

I upgraded to beta.23 and started to get an error when created a new project using 'ionic start foo --v2 --verbose'.
The error in red says 
 "Unable to spawn commandError: spawn npm ENOENT (CLI v2.0.0-beta.23)."

I have npm installed and can run from Windows 8 cmd line. 
I tried upgrade to node v5.9.1.
I confirmed npm is in the PATH environment variable and can run npm from cmd shell.
Any ideas how to fix or debug further would be appreciated.

Here is the complete output:

```
   C:\ionic2>ionic start foo --v2 --verbose
   Task setting: title=start, name=start, summary=Starts a new Ionic project in the
    specified PATH, [options]=any flags for the command, <PATH>=directory for the n
    ew project, [template]=Starter templates can either come from a named     template,

   (ex: tabs, sidemenu, blank),
   a Github repo, a Codepen url, or a local directory.
   Codepen url,
Defaults to Ionic "tabs" starter template, --appname|-a=Human readable name     for
the app (Use quotes around the name), --id|-i=Package name for <widget id>     confi
g, ex: com.mycompany.myapp, title=Skip npm package installation,     boolean=true, t
itle=Create a basic structure without Cordova requirements, boolean=true,     title=
   Setup the project to use Sass CSS precompiling, boolean=true, title=List starter
 templates available, boolean=true, --io-app-id=The Ionic.io app ID to use, --te
mplate|-t=Project starter template, boolean=true, title=Start a Ionic v2 project
, boolean=true, title=(with --v2 only) Use TypeScript in starter, --zip-file|-z=
URL to download zipfile for starter template, module=./ionic/start, disableChang
ePwd=true
Utils.preprocessCliOptions _=[start, foo], skip-npm=false, no-cordova=false, w=f
alse, sass=false, s=false, list=false, l=false, v2=true, v=false, typescript=fal
se, -ts=false, verbose=true, $0=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\bradtk
e\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic

One awesome Ionic app coming right up...

Creating Ionic app in folder C:\ionic2\foo based on tabs project
     Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip
     [=============================]  100%  0.0s
     Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-          
       tabs/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Installing npm packages...
Running exec command: npminstall
Utils.fail Unable to run spawn commandError: spawn npm ENOENT undefined
Utils.fail stack undefined
Utils.errorHandler is set, calling that now
Cli.Utils.errorHandler msg Unable to run spawn commandError: spawn npm ENOENT st
ring

Unable to run spawn commandError: spawn npm ENOENT (CLI v2.0.0-beta.23)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.0 (cordova-lib@undefined)
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.23
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.13
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v5.9.1
```

Regards,
bruce

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the exact same issue.  Worked in beta 22.

Reverting to the earlier beta resolved the issue:

```
npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.22
```

Comment: Thanks.  The downgrade to beta.22 did the trick (ENOENT) error.  I am able to create new project.  FWIW, when I create a project using 'ionic start foo --v2',  I get a nasty red message about cordova version must be greater than 4.2.  But my cordova is 6.1.  Not sure what is going on here or the impact.

Comment: We are now on 2.0.0-beta.29. Does anyone know if this issue is now properly fixed in 29, or should we still be downgrading to 22? And how would upgrading affect things if the initial project was now made using 22...

Comment: Wondering if this didn't reach ionic yet!

Answer (score 7):

Move into folder of your application and run `npm install`. I don't know what is happening but sound like `start` script trying to execute `npminstall` rather than `npm install`:

```
Installing npm packages...
Running exec command: npminstall
```

Comment: I also had to run elevated on Win10 as well as manual npm install.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the CLI on windows. Downgrading to cli beta22 can work as workaround for now, but this will be fixed in the next release

Comment: @mhartington, Hi Mike, I'm on Mac, but my colleague experienced this issue on Windows, even in version 26. We're now on version 29, has this issue been fixed yet? Or should he continue to stay on downgrade of 22. And how will it impact if he's on 22 and im on 29...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading npm worked for me. 
npm install -g npm