# ionic 2 ubuntu 15.0.4 not working

Tags: ubuntu, ionic2

I was trying to setup a ionic 2 development environment on ubuntu 15.0.4 desktop but it didn't work:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ ionic start testaaa

One awesome Ionic app coming right up...

Creating Ionic app in folder /home/xxx/testaaa based on tabs project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive /master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Installing npm packages...
✗ ERROR WITH START undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
✗ There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
xxx@ubuntu:~$ npm -v
2.15.0
xxx@ubuntu:~$ ionic -v
2.0.0-beta.23
```

I am new to ionic. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see that you are trying with Ionic beta 23. Please revert back to beta 22 and try again. You could use the below command.

```
npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.22
```

(As said by mike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238862/enoent-error-when-doing-ionic-start), this issue will be resolved in the next release of ionic).

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: YES! That solved my issue. My first question on stackoverflow and the first answer I recieved. Many thanks Raja. How can I give you credit? Just mark it as answer?

Comment: That's okay... (I was stuck in this issue too.. Glad to help you.. Thanks)

Comment: @RajaYogan please check this out    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685757/getting-error-after-installing-ionic2-i-am-unable-to-create-an-ionic1-project?noredirect=1#comment60961424_36685757